# Contains performs MUCH slower with variable vs constant string SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

For some unknown reason I'm running into a problem when passing a variable to a full text search stored procedure performs many times slower than executing the same statement with a constant value. Any idea why and how can that be avoided?

This executes very fast:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE CONTAINS (comments, '123')
```

This executes very slowly and times out:

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm nvarchar(30)
SET @SearchTerm = '123'
SET @SearchTerm = '"' + @SearchTerm + '"'

SELECT * FROM table
WHERE CONTAINS (comments, @SearchTerm)
```

Does this make any sense???

Comment: Aren't these two different queries - searching for '123' vs '"123"'?

Comment: Yes, which doesn't make any difference. Parameter vs "constant" does

Comment: Ran into the same issue, pretty annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the same issue with trying to use a variable for top. SQL Server is not able to tune a query that is using a variable in this way.

You should try using the execsql command.

Comment: Yeah this actually did the trick, I'm a bit confused, because I'm using something almost the same in a different database, and it works fine with the parameter.

exec sp_executesql @sql works great though

Answer (score 2):

does this run slow: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONTAINS (comments, N'123')` ??

you are using a varchar `'123'` in the first example and a nvarchar variable in the second example. This type conversion could be causing you the problem.  What is the column defined as?

Also why wrap the variable's value in `"` double qoutes, but not do the same in the first example.  When you run the exact same queries using a literal and a variable do the run differently?

Comment: No N'123' runs just as fast. CONTAINS actually does an implicit conversion of NVARCHAR

Comment: I was trying different combination, wrapping in quotes, using char, varchar, nvarchar, etc. None of that made any difference

Comment: @Greg R, Whats with the `"` double quotes?  run `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` and then your two different example (except make them both search the exact same string).  Look at the execution plans, are they different?

Comment: if @SearchTerm is an stored procedure input parameter, you might check out parameter sniffing: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=sql+server+parameter+sniffing&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&num=100&lr=&as_filetype=&ft=i&as_sitesearch=&as_qdr=all&as_rights=&as_occt=any&cr=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&safe=images

Comment: Query plans are vastly different for a "constant" vs a parameter. They are the same for "" vs just ''

Comment: Parameter sniffing didn't work either, only sp_executesql seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I think Matt b is right. The first query you are searching for

```
123
```

In the second query, you are searching for

```
'123'
```

The second query with the quotes is probably returning no results, and your program is probably timing out, not the query.